# What are some ADFS alternatives for doing single sign on for an ASP.NET app with users in active directory?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, single-sign-on

Needs to be secure and able to handle thousands of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out ADAM and AzMan.

ADAM is Active Directory Application Mode.  There is a how-to guide at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998331.aspx

AzMan is Authorization Manager.  There is a how-to guide at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998336.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Three alternatives to ADFS are

- [Symplified](http://www.symplified.com/) - Various product options
- [Ping](https://www.pingidentity.com/) - SaaS product
- Forgerock - This is an open platform

All integrate with AD in some way